# How to concat javascripts imports with Node/Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, concatenation

I'm looking for a way to concatenate imports or something alike from JavaScripts files which are being processed/minified by Gulp. This would allow for dynamically including/excluding plugins while not having to restart the gulp process.

Say Gulp is processing file xxx.js  and that file got an import or something alike in it, i would like it to be inlined in xxx.js instead of ending up as an require('zzz.js')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to incude/inline a file into another, try https://github.com/coderhaoxin/gulp-file-include works also for anytype of file so also **.js** files

Answer (score 1):

I use Webpack nowadays which does everything I want